# How to get another html tag value using this property

Tags: javascript, html

I have a buttton inside a table.

```
<input type="button" onclick="I_Have('IS-12-78',this)" class="i_have_it" value="Yes, I have">
```

When I click the button I need to get the value of select box in the same row.
I haven't maintained separate class or id for this select box.

[image]

```
function I_Have(itm_id,obj)
{
    xmlReq=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlReq.open("POST","./requests/store.jsp",false);
    xmlReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlReq.send("item="+itm_id+"&wt=1");
    if(xmlReq.responseText.trim()!="")
    {
      alert(xmlReq.responseText)
      obj.style.display="none"
      return false
    }
    //obj.innerHTML("Used")
    obj.setAttribute('onclick','I_Dont_Have("'+itm_id+'",this)')
    obj.setAttribute('value','No, I dont have')
    obj.setAttribute('class','i_dont_have_it')
}
```

Using "this"(passed into the function) property can I get the value of select box in javascript.

Comment: Provide please your html code.

Comment: I don't think setting the `value` attribute is going to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dom object's `previousElementSibling` property:

```
this.previousElementSibling.value
```

Have a look on [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yg63twLv/) fiddle.

But this will only work if `select` is immediate sibling of your `button` element.

If that's not your case then first get the parent element then reach to your required element:

```
window.callback = function(obj){
    var parent = obj.parentElement;
    // Uncomment following to get value from nearest <TD> if your htmls is structured in table
    //parent = parent.parentElement;
    var select = parent.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    alert(select.value);
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yg63twLv/2/) is updated fiddle.

Comment: its works for me. I have added one line into your solution as I have select box and button in separate <TD>.Thanks

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi then please mark it as answer. Thanks